# C# or VB scaling the text being sent to a printer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, printing

[image]

I am using this to print text to a label printer:

```
Private Sub PrintTextControl_PrintPage(
    ByVal sender As System.Object, 
    ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) 
    Handles PrintTextControl.PrintPage
    '.....
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", font1, Brushes.Black, x, y, strFormat)
    '.....
End Sub
```

It works well, except that the standard fonts are quite wide for the label printer, even the "Arial Narrow".

I like the Arial/Sanserif style fonts as they are clean and clear. I looked into 3rd party non-standard fonts, but no luck finding any Airal/Sanserif style clean clear fonts.

Is there a way to scale the text to "squeeze" them horizontally? I am not talking about using a smaller font, as the whole word will become smaller. I want it to keep the same height, just scale it narrower.

Comment: Is this wpf?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontstretch.aspx

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?627135-Getting-Font-Kerning-Values

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. It is a dll. Works for Winform app and web app in our company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Private Sub PrintTextControl_PrintPage(
    ByVal sender As System.Object, 
    ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) 
    Handles PrintTextControl.PrintPage
    '.....
    Dim scaleMatrix As New Matrix()
    scaleMatrix.Scale(0.8, 1)
    e.Graphics.Transform = scaleMatrix
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", font1, Brushes.Black, x, y, strFormat)
    '.....
End Sub
```

Just replace the 0.8 with the scale value appropriate for your printer.

Comment: Great. Looks like it is what I need. I am testing it out now.